# Access Database slow opening process when multiple users

Tags: database, performance, ms-access

**Situation :** I made an Access Database which runs 4 Update Queries + 1 SQL update statement in an AutoExec Macro as soon as a user opens it before displaying all the updated information in a Form with conditional formatting applied to it.

This database will be used (editted/read) by multiple users at the same time. So far, if only 1 user opens it it's fine.

**But** if multiple users do, the 1st one who opens it sees the Form after about 10 seconds whereas the 2nd sees it after 60 seconds or more and navigation through it is really slowed down.

Any ideas on how I can fix this ?

I currently think that this can be fixed with the Advanced Client Settings from the Access Option and these are my settings at the moment :

[image]

**EDIT :** The Database in question is NewVersion.accdb and I asked all users to open this one.

[image]

Comment: You could start by deselecting _Open databases by record-level locking_.

Comment: Just did this, no differences in term of performance

Comment: What architecture are you using? Does each user have a copy of the programming while all are sharing one copy of the data, or is everyone opening the same monolithic .accdb file?

Comment: See the edit in my post, I added a picture of the folder's content. everyone is using the same _.accdb_ file. As soon as the 1st user opens it ( NewVersion.accdb), a _.laccdb_ version appears too (NewVersion.laccdb)

Comment: You should split your database and give each user a local copy of the front end. You will end up with all sorts of issues otherwise. Have a read http://www.hitechcoach.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=35:split-your-access-database-into-application-anddata

Comment: I'll read this now thanks

Comment: @Minty Good news : now each user can save his modifications and by clicking "Refresh All" in the Datasheet Tab they can see the modifications of others too. Issue : The opening time is still as slow as before

Comment: Are your tables indexed correctly? How many records are being queried? Can you post up the SQL of the queries involved ?

Comment: Yes tables well indexed. Approx. 200 records only. The 4 Update queries are the same but applied on different fields, here's one's SQL : `UPDATE 12Dec SET [12Dec].[Days Since Request] = DateDiff("d",[12Dec].[Date DHL Submitted],[12Dec].[Date part Received])
WHERE ((([12Dec].[Date part Received]) Is Not Null));` Then the last query (5th) has this SQL : `UPDATE 12Dec
Set [WPRC Part] = 'YES' 
WHERE
PartNo.value in (SELECT SparePartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List)
OR PartNo.value in (SELECT SerialPartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List)`

Comment: Two things spring to mind - Firstly you probably shouldn't need that first Update. You can calculate that time / data difference and display as required. Secondly the use of the Subqueries in the last update as the IN clauses are probably not very efficient, and look to me as if they could easily by replaced by a correct Join of tables / queries.  Very worried that you have a table called 12Dec as well... it implies poor data layout?

Comment: For the first UPDATE, I need it because the `[Date part Received]` will be eddited manually. The above SQL is the case where it is not null. If it is Null, I use DateDiff = [Date]-[Date DHL Submitted]. I need those 4 updates before displaying the form since there is a conditional formatting on that form where the color depends on the value of [Days Since Request]. For your 2nd point I could probably use a Join, yes you're right but since PartNo is a field which allow multiple values in each of its record it makes it harder. For the name of the table, it's a detail since users use the form only

Comment: I understand the conditional formatting, but you can still caclulate those values in a query for the form where they are displayed - not need to store and update another field at all.

Multivalued fields are a massive pain - and almost certainly why you are having issues. They don't scale well - and as you have found, make including the data stored in them awkward to work with. If you were to store that data in a normalised fashion a simple join would solve your issue. Indexes will be of no use on a multi-value field, which can have an horrible impact on performance.